# When using express-session once you log in, every other device APPEARS to be logged in, how do I fix this?

Tags: node.js, express, express-session

So I'm currently using express-session to create a simple login system and when I log in at all, it doesn't stay on THAT device, every other device will show as logged in to that account as well. When I console.logged the session it showed that those other devices dont even have the req.session.loggedin identifier, but still shows up as logged in on the page. Is there something that I'm missing?

`

```
const app = express();
app.use(function(req, res, next) {  
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.headers.origin);
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
});  
const router = express.Router();
const redis = require('redis');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const redisStore = require('connect-redis')(session);
const { fstat } = require('fs');
const client  = redis.createClient();
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(session({
    secret: 'secret',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));
```

`

`

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
     let connection = mysql.createConnection(db_config);
     console.log(req.session.loggedin)
     if (req.session.loggedin) {
        app.locals.username = req.session.username
    }  if (req.session.admin === 1){
        app.locals.admin = true
    } else {
        app.locals.admin = false;
    }
     connection.connect(function(err, result) {
     })
     let query = connection.query('SELECT * FROM posts ORDER by date desc', function (err, result, fields) {
      if (Object.keys(result).length != 0){
          res.render('templates/index', { result });
          connection.end();
          } else {
               res.send(404);
               connection.end();
          }
      })

  });
```

`

`

```
app.post('/login', function(req, res) {
    var username = req.body.username;
    var password = Buffer.from(req.body.password).toString('base64');
    if (username && password) {
        let connection = mysql.createConnection(db_config);
        connection.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? AND password = ?', [username, password], function(error, result, fields) {
            if (result.length > 0) {
                req.session.loggedin = true;
                req.session.username = username;
                req.session.admin = result.admin;
            } else {
                res.send('SUCCESS');
            }
            res.end();
        });
    } else {
        res.send('Please enter Username and Password!');
        res.end();
    }
});
```

`

I tried a multitude of different things that I could think of, but it just doesn't make sense to me, could someone help me make sense of it? Even when im using other devices it does not show the session identifier of being logged in so theres no reason that my page should even be showing

Heres what it shows for the user that is actually logged in
`Session {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      cookie: { path: '/', _expires: null, originalMaxAge: null, httpOnly: true },                                                                                                                                                                 loggedin: true,                                                                                                                                                                                                                              username: 'USERNAME'                                                                                                                                                                                                                     }`

heres what it shows for the user that isnt even logged in
`Session {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      cookie: { path: '/', _expires: null, originalMaxAge: null, httpOnly: true }                                                                                                                                                                }`

Comment: forgot to mention, redisstore, client, and bodyparser are not in use, I forgot to remove those.

Answer (score 0):

So I found that instead of doing `app.locals`, I just grab the session and feed it through the `res.render` so simply put:

```
let session = req.session
res.render('templates/index', { result, session });
```

It now works for me